# How do I find scrollview contentoffset Y point to make visible the selected text.

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview

I want to implement a text search capability using a textview inside a scrollview.  I have wired up a textview with a "previous" and "next" button.  When the user clicks either button it should scroll to the word/sentence being searched.

Using string attributes and NSRange I have been able to find and highlight the user selected word or sentence.

```
var colorText = new NSMutableAttributedString(fileString, attrFont);
var attrHL = new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red };
colorText.AddAttributes(attrHL.Dictionary, new NSRange(idxStart, length);
```

But I can't figure out how to make the scrollview scroll to the selected text and keep it visible.  Since the text displayed in the textview is larger than the size of the scrollview I have to use contentoffset.Y to move the visible view but how do I find the Y point of the selected word/sentence?

Right now if the text displayed is larger than the view size the searched for text does highlight but it may be off the visible view and I have to manually scroll down to see the highlighted text.

Comment: Have you looked at `UITextView`'s `.scrollRangeToVisible()` method? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618613-scrollrangetovisible

Comment: is the whole text in a single label? or a textView? give us more info about the view hierarchy you have there

Comment: I have tried Textview's ScrollRangetoVisible but does not work (does not scroll). I believe I have to use scrollview's ScrollRectToVisible but that requires a CGRect() which I don't know how to obtain from the highlighted text.  If I can get the X, Y point of the start of the highlighted text I should be about to use ScrollRectToVisible().

Comment: The text is in a textview not a label since the text can be very long, hence requiring this search capability.

Comment: If you are making your text view taller (or wider) than the scroll view that contains it, you're asking for problems. There will be conflicting "scroll gestures" and, as you're seeing, problems keeping the text "in view".

Comment: UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView and setting my textview.scrollenabled to false should bypass any scroll gesture conflicts since I'm relying on the enclosing scrollview to pan and zoom a content that's larger than the visible view.  I believe the solution to be to use scrollview.ScrollRectToVisible() but somehow I have to tell it where to scroll to by providing the contentOffet X,Y values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the `NSRange` (named `range`) corresponding to the bit of text you want to scroll to, that your `UIScrollView` is named `scrollView` and your `UITextView` is named `textView`.

• Turn the `NSRange` value into a `UITextRange`:

```
var startPosition = textView.GetPosition(textView.BeginningOfDocument, range.Location);
var endPosition = textView.GetPosition(startPosition, range.Length);

var textRange = textView.GetTextRange(startPosition, endPosition);
```

• Get the `CGRect` corresponding to the position of that `textRange` in your `textView`:

```
var rect = textView.GetFirstRectForRange(textRange);
```

• Then scroll your `scrollView` to that `rect`, assuming that the position of your `textView` is `(0, 0)` in the `scrollView`'s content area (otherwise you'll have to offset `rect`):

```
scrollView.ScrollRectToVisible(rect, true);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Olivier.  from your suggestion I was able to get the ContentOffSet.Y value.